# EGODatabase error on using their own example code !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, sqlite

I just added the EGODatabase for using SQLite in my project. I created a sample database with a table 'posts' and added it to the project. However on executing the following line from their own example I get the error: Too many arguments to function 'executeQuery'.

```
EGODatabaseResult* result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_user_id` = ?", [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know EGODatabase, but if I had to make a guess I would try

```
EGODatabaseResult* result = [database executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_user_id` = %d", 10]];
```

from EgoDatabase.h:

```
// Execute Query
- (EGODatabaseResult*)executeQueryWithParameters:(NSString*)sql, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

- (EGODatabaseResult*)executeQuery:(NSString*)sql;
- (EGODatabaseResult*)executeQuery:(NSString*)sql parameters:(NSArray*)parameters;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things I see wrong. First, you say your table is called 'post' but you trying to query 'posts'. Second, your query string isn't being formed properly. Assuming you fix the first error, try using something like this:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_user_id` = %d", 10];
EGODatabaseResult* result = [database executeQuery:queryString];
```

That should fix both problems.